# How to avoid deploying ASP.NET MVC3 application in subpath on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, deployment, iis-7.5

When I deploy an ASP.NET MVC3 application to an IIS 7.5 on WindowsServer 8RC2 it is only accesible under this url: mydomain.com/mvcsite instead of just mydomain.com

I am using MSDeploy to install the app from deployment package built in visual studio.

On the IIS I have a website configured and inside this an Application named 'mvcsite'.

Do I need Url rewriting to make this work or can some default root path be configured in the IIS 7.5?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1446728/1182982)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Advanced settings** of the site (right click on the site -> **Manage Web Site** -> **Advanced Settings...**), you can change the **Physical path** to the path where your `mvcsite` application resides.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I just had to create a website without creating an application beneath.

Comment: actually, I'm in the opposite situation as you were. I'm able to create a website, point it to a folder in `wwwroot` and then deploy application contents inside that folder, so to have that at `domain/`. Instead I'd like to create a website, and in the end have the app located at `domain/myApp`. How to do that?