# Asp.net: relative paths not working when deployed IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, filepath

I spent almost 2-3 good hours on this and im here now, as the question states. The project works fine in VS but when I deploy/publish it through IIS (to access it on local network) some files (well most of them) aren't accessible. This happened when I added the Metronic theme within my web project. The files are like:

```
  <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
```

OR

```
<img src="../assets/pages/img/logo.png" alt="place Logo Here" />
```

Now once its published, it throws me a pile of errors that it could not find any of those files.

[image: State when running on VS]

[image: State Once its published to IIS]

Notice: the url in both the pictures, the deployed project is under another folder. is it the culprit?

I am trying to figure out a solution that works for both VS debugging and the deployed project.

What I have tried is:

1: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-how-to-run-a-root-site-with-the-local-web-server-using-vs-2005-sp1

2: [Deploying asp.net application to root directory in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446728/deploying-asp-net-application-to-root-directory-in-iis)

3: [How to avoid deploying ASP.NET MVC3 application in subpath on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912449/how-to-avoid-deploying-asp-net-mvc3-application-in-subpath-on-iis-7-5?noredirect=1&lq=1)

4: [ASP.NET WebForms: Why do relative paths within user controls work locally, but not when deployed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866865/asp-net-webforms-why-do-relative-paths-within-user-controls-work-locally-but-n)

5: [IIS virtual directory and ASP.NET directory paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449267/iis-virtual-directory-and-asp-net-directory-paths)

6: [Relative path from site root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960094/relative-path-from-site-root)

Comment: is `g2` your _application_ root (and marked as such)? Clarify how you set this up in IIS (particularly what `g2` is).

Comment: g2 is the folder that I created inside wwwroot which has the published files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use absolute paths starting with '~/' as the base directory of your Web Site / Web App.

```
e.g. "~/assets/pages/img/logo.png"
```

and when working in Code Behind use the

```
Server.MapPath("~/")
```

as Base Folder.

Comment: what about the rest of the files? like this one: `<link href="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and when working in Code Behind use the, im sorry what?

Comment: href="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css"  would then be href="~/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" if assets is in your base directory.

Comment: Code Behind is either your Website.aspx.cs or the Code in the Controller when you are using MVC.

Comment: sure. let me check this

Answer (score 0):

> `g2` is the folder that I created inside wwwroot which has the published files

- If your intent was to make that a "sub application" (of whatever is the "parent" in `wwwroot` then it can be a ["virtual directory"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771804(v=ws.10)) or a ["sub application"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc772042(v=ws.10))
- If your intent was to publish it as it's own application, separate from any other, then you don't have to publish it under `wwwroot`. You create new [IIS sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc772350(v=ws.10)).

The previous answer using `~/` is based on what is defined as the *application root*

Hth...