# ASP.NET MVC4 only showing @RenderBody content on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4

**ASP.NET MVC4 only showing @RenderBody content on IIS7**

Setup: I've got a VM running Windows 7 upon which I've installed IIS7, MVC3 & MVC4 with Web Platform Installer. I've added a new website in IIS using a .NET 4.0 application pool, and then used the Visual Studio 2012 publish option to publish an MVC4 web app to the website's root directory.

The problem is that the only output I am getting is whatever is in the individual views. There is no layout, nothing other than the @RenderBody content.

It works fine when I preview it with Visual Studio.

This is my _Layout.cshtml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
    <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/favicon.ico">

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- this is decorative -->
        <div class="topbar"></div>

        <div class="row header">
            <div class="five columns logo">            
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/logo.png")">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="seven columns nav">
                @Html.Partial("_TopNavigationPartial")
            </div>
        </div>

        @RenderBody()

        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns box-padding">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="row footer">
                        <div class="six columns copyright">&copy; 2013 snip.</div>
                        <div class="six columns nav">
                            @Html.Partial("_BottomNavigationPartial")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)     
    </body>
    </html>
```

All that will be output though is what is in the view, e.g:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns box-padding">
            <div class="box">
                <h1>Home</h1>
                <p>You are here: Home/Index</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Anyone have any idea why this might be so?

It's probably just that I haven't set up IIS7 right.

**Edit:** I just uploaded the `Internet application` and it has done the exact same thing. Only the view content is being output. So it's definitely something in IIS.

**Edit 2:** I have set up an `Internet application` as an application in IIS but still it returns the view content only. Weird.

**Edit 3:** Got it working, not sure how. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DCug.gif

Comment: Did you look at the generated HTML source code of the browser? Does it contain only the view content? Did you make sure that on your web server the `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` and `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` files exist and have been successfully deployed?

Comment: Correct, only that view content in the source. Nothing else. I can still navigate to other views. The web server has both of those files and in the right places.

Comment: Do you have a definition for your master layout in the derived views? @{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/<MASTERLAYOUT>.cshtml";}

Comment: In `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` I have: `@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }` but not in the actual views.

Comment: Could there be some custom action filters running and stripping the Layout?

Comment: Not as far as I know, this is basically the `Basic project` with controllers, views and a layout added. Nothing more. I don't think it's even looking at the layout file, I just removed part of it and it didn't change a thing. I think it's bypassing it completely.

Comment: did you make this a website or an application under root in IIS?

Comment: Made a fresh website with the directory to the published files. When I add an application I get `Invalid Application Path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this. Not sure exactly what was the problem, but I was making a new website and then dragging the published files into it, which wasn't working.

I then added an application to the default website, which worked, but then I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446741/1138620) which explained that the default website itself is an application.

So in the end I just copied the published files into the default root directory and it worked.